# If all firms in an economy are in monopolistic competition with constant elasticity of substitution, can they profit-maximize at $MC=MR=AC$?

Tags: microeconomics

Suppose all firms are monopolistically competitive with constant elasticity of substitution. Can they profit maximize at the quantity point $MC=AC$ (So $P \neq MC$ but $Q$ is set at where $MC=MR=AC$ is established)?

By constant elasticity of substitution, I mean that $\epsilon = -(\partial Q_j/\partial P_i)/(Q_j/P_i)$ is constant for $\forall i \neq j$ where $i,j$ refers to firms, $Q$ refers to quantity, and $P$ refers to price.

Comment: What here has the "constant elasticity of substitution" property? Production? Demand? Supply? Revenues? Costs? Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry for my omission. Now I clarified.

Comment: Your title had a condition on MR, but the question does not. Can you clarify?

Comment: Clarified. It's just ordinary profit-maximization stuff - in almost all economic structure, firms set their quantity at $MC=MR$ point (it's just first-order condition) - though if firms are not perfect competition type, then $P \neq MC$ - I omitted in the main text because it was so obvious anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The long-run picture for a firm in monopolistically competitive industry should look like this:

[image]

The level of production is pinned down by where MR=MC. Price will be equal to AC at that point, so the firm has zero profits.

If the firm was producing at the point where MC=AC, it would have positive profits, which would encourage entry into the industry, shifting the demand in and reducing profits to zero.

Comment: If by MC=AC, you are referring to the intersection of MC and AC, that would generate negative profits. AR<AC.

Comment: @Pburg I think profit maximization means that the MR curve would also have to pass trough the point where MC=AC, which means AR (or demand) must lie above it, so AR>AC at that point, indicating positive profits.

Comment: I see, my mistake. I thought you were referring to the MC=AC point on the same graph you have included.